# What should I do if questioner not at all trying?

Tags: discussion

What should I do if questioner not at all trying the logic or suggestion given and asking for the full code again and again without attempting ?

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example?

Comment: Just walk away. Nobody wins in an argument with a help vampire.

Comment: @DavidRobinson This is the recent example she asked the same question again in 24 hours and not trying, it happens many time 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520116/checked-checkbox-remain-through-pagination-using-load-javascript/25520533#25520533

Comment: say him/her to take a tour of the website that how it goes around here

Answer (score 3):

When you have the [required reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to do so, close-vote the newer questions as duplicated of the old ones. If you don't, you can also flag the question as a duplicate.
Downvote too, if necessary.

It appears this specific user asked only 3 questions since he/she registered, 6 days ago. All 3 of them about the same subject. I closed the newer ones as dupes of the older ones, courtesy of [Mjolnir](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/78/javascript?userid=1835379)

Comment: I have already voted it as duplicate